# How to create car start/stop button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, user-experience

I want to create car selling app. I want use car start/stop button on onboarding screen & on tap play car engine start sound? Could you help for creating this widget?

Car start/stop button widget

[image]

Creating car start/stop button

Comment: I would use a Column and have one of the widgets depend on a boolean, if the button is clicked return a green widget , if the button is false(not clicked) return a grey button.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CarButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CarButton({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isPressed = false;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        isPressed = !isPressed;
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          isPressed
              ? Container(
                  height: 10,
                  width: 30,
                  color: Colors.green,
                )
              : Container(
                  height: 10,
                  width: 30,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
          Text('Start'),
          Text('Stop')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you may have to make it a stateful widget and use setState in onTap